# Building a C iterator macro with a pre-C99 compiler

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c89

My code, which must be compiled with a pre-C99 compiler (we're working on updating but it's an enormous task), is calling into a utility library designed with C99 in mind.  In particular, these utilities define a hashmap type and provide a macro to iterate through it similar to the following:

```
#define MAP_FOREACH(key, val, map) \
    for (struct _map_iterator iter __attribute__((cleanup(_map_iter_cleanup))); \
        (key) = iter->pair->key, \
        (value) = iter->pair->value; \
        iter = iter->get_next_cb())
```

The actual code has a bit more to it (functionality to make sure the iterator's name is unique, etc.), but this covers the meat of my problem which is that pre-1999 versions of C don't support initializing variables inside a for loop.  Now the obvious fix here would be to move the initialization outside of the loop, with code that looks like:

```
// Doesn't work
#define MAP_FOREACH(key, val, map) \
    struct _map_iterator iter __attribute__((cleanup(_map_iter_cleanup)));
    for (; \
        (key) = iter->pair->key, \
        (value) = iter->pair->value; \
        iter = iter->get_next_cb())
```

The issue is that `__attribute__((cleanup(_map_iter_cleanup)))` bit.  According to the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html), that defines cleanup code attached to the variable, which gets run when the variable goes out of scope.  Because we've moved the iterator declaration outside the for loop, its scope has changed, and the cleanup code gets run elsewhere.  Unfortunately, other parts of the library rely on the iterator getting cleaned up immediately - the map keeps track of how many iterators have been initiated, and throws an error if it's destroyed before they're all gone.

I've been trying and failing to think of a clean way around this for a few days now, but I'm coming up short.  I don't really want to re-implement the macro-plus-cleanup in the pre-C99 code, but this library is used all over the place and changing the API to include a post-iteration cleanup call would be painful, not to mention inelegant.

Has anyone encountered this sort of thing before and know a way around it?

**EDIT:** we're using GCC 4.2.2 with the -std=c89 option

Comment: I'm a bit surprised there is a compiler that doesn't support `-std=c99` but does support `__attribute__((cleanup()))`. What compiler is this?

Comment: Oh, so it [does](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) support C99. If for some reason you can't use C99 for the entire project, why not use it for just the problematic files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to create an alternative macro that must be used in C89 code. You'd have to extend the scope and encapsulate the action, such as by making a new set of macros as follows:

```
/* Force a compiler error if non-C99 code uses the C99 macro. */
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
/* C99 code */
#define MAP_FOREACH(key, val, map) \
    for (struct _map_iterator iter __attribute__((cleanup(_map_iter_cleanup))); \
        (key) = iter->pair->key, \
        (value) = iter->pair->value; \
        iter = iter->get_next_cb())
#endif

/* C89-compatible macro */
#define MAP_FOREACH_DO(key, val, map, statement) \
do{ struct _map_iterator iter __attribute__((cleanup(_map_iter_cleanup))); \
for (; \
    (key) = iter->pair->key, \
    (value) = iter->pair->value; \
    iter = iter->get_next_cb()) \
    { \
        statement; \
    } \
}while(0)
```

That way for simple statements you can just do something like:

`MAP_FOREACH_DO(..., printf(%s=%s\n", key, value));`

... and for more complex statements you can call a function.

Ideally, of course, you just switch to C99 (at least for the relevant code) and be done with it.

Comment: I think this is the way I'm going to go on this one.  It's not a beautiful solution, but it should do the trick.

Comment: I ended up writing a MAP_FN_FOREACH that takes the map, a pointer to a user-defined context, and a function to call with the signature fn(void *context, const char *key, void *value).

Answer (score 4):

I am not fully aware of the missing functionalities of pre-C99 standard, but I think you could do it like the following:

```
#define MAP_FOREACH(key, val, map) \
    {
        struct _map_iterator iter __attribute__((cleanup(_map_iter_cleanup)));
        for (; \
            (key) = iter->pair->key, \
            (value) = iter->pair->value; \
            iter = iter->get_next_cb())
```

And then wherever you use it, you'd have to append the loop with an extra closing curly bracket `}`.

Comment: That would probably work.  However, as I said above this library is used all over the place (most of our code base is C99-OK).  It would cause a lot of code churn to go and make that change everywhere, but more importantly it's not an intuitive pattern - you'd need to go read the library carefully to understand why your code needs an extra curly brace to compile.

Comment: if you do this, define another macro `#define MAP_FOREACH_END   }` to encapsulate the close brace and ensure that you use it exactly once for each `MAP_FOREACH`.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away with something like:

```
#define MAP_FOREACH(key, val, map) \
struct _map_iterator iter;
for (; \
    (key) = iter->pair->key, \
    (value) = iter->pair->value ? 1 : _map_iter_cleanup(&iter), 0; \
    iter = iter->get_next_cb())
```

explicitly calling the cleanup function when the loop condition is false.

Unfortunately, this will fail if there are any `MAP_FOREACH` loops that exit via `break;` -- the iterator won't be cleaned up.  You could fix these by adding another macro:

```
#define MAP_FOREACH_BREAK  { _map_iter_cleanup(&iter); break; }
```

and replacing all the problematic breaks with this macro.

Comment: `return` should be wrapped as well. The trouble with this approach is that if someone forgets to use `MAP_FOREACH_BREAK` instead of simply `break`, the code will compile and maybe even appear to work, except the iterator won't get cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

gcc has had statement expressions, complete with local variables, almost [forever](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.2/gcc_4.html#SEC62), including the [typeof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.2/gcc_4.html#SEC68) extension:

```
({ int y = foo (); int z;
   if (y > 0) z = y;
   else z = - y;
   z; })
```

(the links above are to gcc-2.95.2 manuals!). So you should already have all pieces to build something cleaner at hand.

Comment: Statement expressions serve to treat a statement or block as an expression that evaluates to a value. The OP must write a macro that expands to a `for` loop with very specific (and compiler-dependent) semantics of the loop iterator variable. How do you propose to use statement expressions to achieve this goal?